# How to find datatype of an embedded object in Python, in the absence of prototypes and headers

Tags: python, types

I am maintaining some Python code that I inherited from someone else.

When I have a long trail of imported modules, all along which some data structures are built up (mostly "dict" entries, whose "value" is another "dict" entry, etc the chain continues).

Deep down, is there a way to find the datatype of an entity (eg. as I browse the code, I'd like to know what is the datatype of the "value" returned by an `iteritems()`). I'm finding this especially cumbersome since Python seems to be a weakly typed language, and there are no prototypes or header files.

Any suggestions? Or is there any way an IDE can help me?

Comment: Are you using Pycharm? You could try marking the source directory as `Sources Root` then see if the Pycharm typehinting (strg + hover over the variable) can figure it out. It will at least lead you to the variable declaration.

Comment: @Darina, no I'm not using Pycharm. I'm somewhat new to Python. I'll try out Pycharm as you suggest, thanks.